# Use i18n with data fetched from Wordpress RestAPI

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

I'm stuck since a while on this problem now and I'm struggling to find answers or peoples that have experienced the same problem.

Also, I'm not a native English speaker and I'm new to programming, so sorry if it's not clear / if my approch is dumb as f


I decided to turn the Wordpress of my company to headless (on Nuxt). Everything was pretty fine until I tried to internationalized the app. The best solution (I think) to manage this task is to use nuxt-i18n, a tool to properly translate the app (strings, paths etc). But this solution seems to not be very compatible with data fetched from the Rest API.


For now I'm trying to passing the data from single page like that :

```html
<script>
import SwitchL from '~/components/LanguageInput.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    SwitchL,
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      fetchRestFr: null,
      fetchRestEn: null,
      i18nData: null,
    }
  },

  i18n: {
    messages: {
      // help
    }
  },

  methods: {
    fetchSomeData() {
      // Get page data in French
      let fetchRestFr = this.$axios.$get(`https://www.company-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?include=42&lang=fr`);
      // Get page data in English
      let fetchRestEn = this.$axios.$get(`https://www.company-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?include=42&lang=en`);

      // Assign data to null variables
      this.fetchRestFr = fetchRestFr[0]
      this.fetchRestEn = fetchRestEn[0]

      // Build the i18n object
      this.dataToI18n();
    },

    dataToI18n() {
      if (this.fetchRestFr && this.fetchRestEn) {
        
        let fr = this.fetchRestFr
        let en = this.fetchRestEn

        let data = {
          messages: {
            fr,
            en
          }
        }

        this.i18nData = data
      }
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchSomeData();
  },

}
</script>
```

An other approch was to use the  tag outside the template section like so :

```json
<i18n>
// Inject the data generated from a function
{
  "en": {
    "data": "here"
  },
  "fr": {
    "data": "ici"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

But I don't find any solution to dynamically inject JSON here.

Last solution is to make things to preper way, by creating JSON file for i18n to referencing, but I think It will be pretty hard for me to do this, and to manage this on long term.

If you have advice, thoughts on this I will be very grateful !

Answer (score 0):

You do usually use some JSON files directly. They will be stored into `/locales/fr.json` with something like this

```json
{
  "here": "ici"
}
```

Then, you'll access it into your `template` with

```html
<template>
  <p>{{ $t('here') }}</p>
</template>
```

And it will handle the `fr/en` switch by the several ways available (manual switch, checking browser's locale, URL's path, cookie etc).

You can check `nuxt-i18n`'s documentation for this and get a proper simple setup quickly here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/

Usually, you won't need to use the `i18n` tag anymore but if you still need to, you can do as explained here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/per-component-translations